# Expected value of the k-th order statistic from uniform random variables

Tags: self-learning, order-statistics, beta-function

I am trying to find the expected value of $X_{(k)}$ 
Here is my work so far:
$$f_{X_{(k)}}(x)=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}f_X(x)[F_{X}(x)]^{k-1}[1-F_X(x)]^{n-k}$$
by $X_i \sim U(0,1)$ this becomes
$$E(X_{(k)})=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\int_0^1 x^{k}[1-x]^{n-k}dx$$
This almost looks like a beta
$$B(a,b) = \int_0^1\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}x^{a-1}[1-x]^{b-1}dx=1$$
$$E(X_{(k)})=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\int_0^1
x^{k}[1-x]^{n-k}dx$$
So we can integrate out the beta pdf
$$a =k+1,b=n-k+1$$ 
$$E(X_{(k)})=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\frac{(k+1)!(n-k+1)!}{(n+2)!}$$
I cannot seem to simplify this to the right answer given in the solutions. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hey there. I just came up with your question. How did you come up with the initial part of your results? Namely the after "here is my work so far". If possible could you share that with me?

Comment: @EmilMirzayev, of the n r.v.s we need exactly k of them to be <=x. This can be done in n choose k ways. Among the chosen k r.v.s the k-th one can be chosen in k ways. Thus the prefactor is k times n choose k

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're messing up in this way:  $\Gamma(m) = (m-1)$! for a positive integer $m$. I'm getting

\begin{align*}
E(X_{(k)}) &=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\int_0^1 x^{k}[1-x]^{n-k}dx \\[5pt]
&= \frac{ \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k) \Gamma(n-k+1)}\int_0^1 x^{k}[1-x]^{n-k}dx \\[5pt]
&=\frac{ \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k) \Gamma(n-k+1)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(n-k+1) }{ \Gamma(n+2)} \int_0^1 \frac{ \Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(n-k+1) } x^{k}[1-x]^{n-k}dx \\[5pt]
&= \frac{ \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k) \Gamma(n-k+1)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(n-k+1) }{ \Gamma(n+2)} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k) \Gamma(n+2)} =  \frac{k}{n+1}.
\end{align*}

Final comment: $X_{(k)} \sim \text{Beta}(k,n+1-k)$, which agrees with above.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF of a beta distribution with parameters $a = k+1$, $b = n-k+1$, is $$\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}, \quad x \in (0,1).$$  This gives you the desired integrand you want to evaluate, so $$1 = \frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)} \int_{x=0}^1 x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \, dx = \frac{(n+1)!}{k! (n-k)!} \int_{x=0}^1 x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \, dx.$$  And now it is evident that there is an extra factor of $(n+1)/k$ on the RHS, so we have $$\frac{k}{n+1} = \frac{n!}{(k-1)! (n-k)!} \int_{x=0}^1 x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \, dx.$$

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if the uniform distribution from which X is sampled has bounds (0, 500) instead of (0, 1), the X_k expected value would be just 500* the result above?