# $X_1... X_n$ are independent random variables distributed $U[0,1]$ and $Y_1...Y_n $ is the decreasing order of $\{ X_i \}_1 ^n$. Find $E[Y_k]$

Tags: probability

My attempt: $F_{Y_k}(a) = P(Y_k\le a)$ and this happens when at most $n-k$ from the $X_i$'s are bigger then $a$.

The probability, $P(X_i > a) = \int_a^1 1 dt = 1-a $ and for $P(X_i\le a) = \int _0^a 1 dt = a$ , form $\{ X_i \}$'s Independence we get:

$P(Y_k\le a) = \sum_{i=1} ^ {i=n-k} {n \choose i}(1-a)^i\cdot (a)^{n-i}$.

Here I'm stuck, I tried to use the fact that $E[Y_k] = \int_0^a 1-F_{Y_k}(t)dt$ but I didn't manage to solve it.

Comment: You might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251604/expected-value-of-the-k-th-order-statistic-from-uniform-random-variables